# Special sum of multinomial coefficients!

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find a explicit formula for the following sum in terms of $n$ and $k$. Any help would be appreciated.

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{a_1 + \dots + a_k = n} \frac{(2n)!}{(2 a_1)! \dots (2 a_k)!} = ?
\end{equation}

Comment: Your thoughts? Anything you have tried?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have tried to compare this with $$ \sum_{a_1 + \cdots + a_k = n} \frac{1}{ a_1 ! \cdots a_k !} = \frac{k^n}{n!}. $$ Or, look at the last sum with the condition that all $ a_j $'s are even. But, I couldn't manage to  obtain an explicit formula!

Comment: You should add this observation in the body of the question.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'll do this in my next question! Thanks! ;-)

Comment: @Mary: If you add it to this question, not only does it improve the quality of the question by adding context, it may also get people to upvote your question.

Comment: Some other proofs are [at this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1146548).

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k)^{2n} = \sum_{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_k=2n}\frac{(2n)!}{a_1!a_2!\cdot\ldots\cdot a_k!} x_1^{a_1} x_2^{a_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_k^{a_k}$$
we may apply the following transformation to isolate in the RHS just the terms for which $a_1$ is even:
$$ (x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k)^{2n} \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left[(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k)^{2n}+(-x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k)^{2n}\right] $$
hence:
$$ S=\sum_{\substack{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_k=2n\\ a_i\text{ even}}}\frac{(2n)!}{a_1!a_2!\cdot\ldots\cdot a_k!}=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{e\in\{-1,+1\}^k}(e_1+e_2+\ldots+e_k)^{2n}$$
that leads to
$$ S = \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}(k-2j)^{2n} $$
resembling (but not being equal) a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). We may expand $(k-2j)^{2n}$ in terms of binomial coefficients and Stirling numbers of the second kind, then compute
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}\binom{|k-2j|}{a} $$
to turn $S$ into a sum of powers of two multiplied by Stirling numbers of the second kind, but that still does not give a "nice" closed formula for $S$.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel all of the multinomial coefficients with odd components, we can average
$$
(\underbrace{\pm1\pm1\pm\dots\pm1}_{k\text{ terms}})^{2n}
$$
which gives
$$
\frac1{2^k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(k-2j)^{2n}
$$
I have not yet been able to simplify this further.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, and by cancelling even components we get a similar formula that $ (-1)^j $ also appears under your sum. However, a precise formula is needed!

Comment: @Mary: in which way robjohn did not provide you a precise formula?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you Jack! I meant an answer which does not involve another (new) sum.

Comment: @Mary: I guess that is pretty impossible. Polynomials or Stirling numbers are defined by sums.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks Jack! Then I need to see how I can apply the current answer!

Comment: @Mary: It would be useful to know exactly the original question, or the problem you are tackling by hoping there is a nice closed formula for your multinomial sum.