# Estimate from above the sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

How to estimate from above the following sums:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^K \sum_{j=0}^{L-K}\binom{K}{i}\binom{L-K}{j} (-1)^i (L-2i-2j)^N
$$

Comment: Not sure if it helps much, but you can rewrite it as $$\sum_{r=0}^{L}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{K}\binom{K}{i}\binom{L-K}{r-i}(-1)^i\right)(L-2r)^N.$$

Comment: Don't know if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3779233/573047) might help.

Comment: I might help to add some context, how you got this sum?

Comment: Thank you. It was a game of some probability sums. Technically calculation of an odd and even pairs of numbers. The content would not help much...